# Is it better to use two-wire or three-wire cable for a bath fan/light unit?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, switch, light, fans

I’m running Romex cable in a bare (framed only) bathroom. End result should be 2 vanity lights on one switch, and then above shower light (recessed LED water-rated) and a separate vent/fan (Delta GBR80) center of bathroom) on another switch.

Is there any coding that would prevent running the shower light wire AND the fan wire to the same box then pigtail to switch? The shower light ceiling is 8’6” high. I didn’t plan to run the shower light with GFCI in mind, only a separate GFCI run for the receptacles near the sinks.

Location: USA

Comment: "Above shower light and separate vent/fan on another switch" means both the light and fan on the same switch?

Comment: Yes. Both scenarios result in the fan and light being on the same switch. Just wondering about the wiring prior to the switch.

Comment: I've attempted to revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. If I'm off the mark, please revise. I'm not sure I follow your post very well.

Comment: I’ve edited my question. I’m more concerned about code compliance, GFCI requirements, etc. Cost and time is secondary.

Comment: Which is "better" depends on which you can achieve more conveniently. Parallel circuits are parallel circuits.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you've got two devices:

1. An exhaust fan
2. An over-shower light

You're looking to have both of them operated by a single switch. You've got two options defined.

1. Run cable from the switch to one device, then a short(ish) hop to the other device.

   - Pros:

     - Uses less cable
   - Cons:

     - Makes it difficult to separate the operation of the two devices in the future should you (or anyone else) decide they want them separated (humidity activated vent fan upgrade?).
2. Run separate cables from the switch to each device.

   - Pros:

     - Makes future upgrades much easier.
   - Cons:

     - Uses more money now to run the extra cable up the wall and across the ceiling.

Proposed *third* option (thanks to isherwood for the idea!):

1. Run a single /3 cable from the switch to one device then the other. Use just one hot wire to control both devices, leaving the other hot wire capped at the switch, cut but connected at the first device, capped at the second device.

   - Pros:

     - Less over all cable.
     - Makes it easy to add separate control in the future.
   - Cons:

     - /3 cable is more expensive than /2 cable, especially if you're purchasing a short amount for a single run.

Since you haven't defined what you consider "better" (spend money now v spend money later? Code compliance? Some other factor I'm not thinking of), it's impossible for *me* to tell *you* what *you* consider "better" (though everyone seems to want to do so).

Therefore, your question is really off-topic since it's opinion based, but I thought I'd be nice and lay out a couple of Pros/Cons for you to help *you* make the decision.

Comment: Thank you. I realized earlier that while neither option is wrong, I think running separate lines to the switch is better for future upgrade purposes. This was my first question posted, so I will work on formatting them differently so to not be opinion based.

Comment: Please go ahead and edit your question now, @DIY_mama80. If you don't it will likely get closed. While you'll still have your info, that's not a nice feeling.

Answer (score 1):

FreeMan's answer covers a lot of possibilities. Two more things to consider:

- Control of fan with a switch/humidity sensor. This could be done with the 3-wire to one device, 2-wire to second device, extra wire unused for now setup (FreeMan's third option) by making use of the unused wire.
- Future replacement of fan with heater/fan. This would require three separate switched hots and three switches. To enable this in the future (you may even want to consider it now) you need /3 to the heater/fan and a *separate* /2 to the light.